# ogre3D compilation under qtcreator but no render window

Tags: c++, 3d, mingw, qt-creator, ogre

I try to compile in qtcreator an OGRE3D example with MINGW! I've managed to obtain no error but I only get a log window containing this

```
    09:56:08: Creating resource group General
    09:56:08: Creating resource group Internal
    09:56:08: Creating resource group Autodetect
    09:56:08: SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
    09:56:08: Registering ResourceManager for type Material
    09:56:08: Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
    09:56:08: Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
    09:56:08: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
    09:56:08: OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
    09:56:08: OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
    09:56:08: OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
    09:56:08: Registering ResourceManager for type Font
    09:56:08: ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
    09:56:08: ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
    09:56:08: ArchiveFactory for archive type EmbeddedZip registered.
    09:56:08: DDS codec registering
    09:56:08: FreeImage version: 3.15.3
    09:56:08: This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
    09:56:08: Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,3fr,arw,bay,bmq,cap,cine,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,drf,dsc,dng,erf,fff,ia,iiq,k25,kc2,kdc,mdc,mef,mos,mrw,nef,nrw,orf,pef,ptx,pxn,qtk,raf,raw,rdc,rw2,rwl,rwz,sr2,srf,srw,sti
    09:56:08: Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
    09:56:08: Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
    09:56:08: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
    09:56:08: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
    09:56:08: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
    09:56:08: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
    09:56:08: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
    09:56:08: MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
```

What should I do to have the render window? thanks a lot for any help

This is my .pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
QT +=widgets
TARGET = qt_ogre
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += D:/Paul/OGRE/OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-1/include/OGRE
INCLUDEPATH += D:/Paul/OGRE/OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-1/boost

win32 {
        LIBS += -LD:/Paul/OGRE/OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-1/lib/debug
        LIBS += -LD:/Paul/OGRE/OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-1/boost/lib/
}

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        #LIBS += -lOgreGUIRenderer_d -lOgreMain_d
       LIBS += libboost_system-mgw47-mt-d-1_51

}
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
#   LIBS += -lOgreGUIRenderer -lOgreMain
        LIBS += "-LD:/Paul/OGRE/OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-1/boost/lib/"
}
# Input
HEADERS += ogrewidget.h
       
SOURCES += main.cpp \
        ogrewidget.cpp
```

This is my main.cpp

> ## include

```
#include "ogrewidget.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow()
    :ogreWidget(0)
    {
        ogreWidget = new OgreWidget;
        setCentralWidget(ogreWidget);
    
        QAction *closeAct = new QAction("Quitter", this);
        connect(closeAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
    
        QAction *changeColorAct = new QAction("Changer la couleur de fond", this);
        connect(changeColorAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(chooseBgColor()));
    
        QMenu *menu = menuBar()->addMenu("Divers");
        menu->addAction(changeColorAct);
        menu->addAction(closeAct);
}

private slots:
    void chooseBgColor()
    {
        QColor c = QColorDialog::getColor();
        ogreWidget->setBackgroundColor(c);
    }

private:
    OgreWidget *ogreWidget;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I don't think the problem comes from Ogre because I have tried a very basic example using irrlicht and I have the same problem!!! it compiles but I don't have the output window
Do you have an idea??
thanks a lot!

Comment: Quite impossible to assist without knowing what exactly you are doing and which code you are using to create the render window. Are you following a particular tutorial and if yes, which one?